# MathJax: How to number and reference multiline equations?

Tags: support, mathjax

I'd like to number multiline equations and reference them, à la [MathJax's Align and Gather environments](http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/test/sample-eqnum.html). Can this be accomplished? If so, how?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In the align environment, I use `\tag` to number. `\label` is also supported by MathJax. `\ref` can be used to reference a line using `\label` and `\tag`.

For example:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=1\label{a}\tag{1}
$$
and reference it here: $\ref{a}$

Comment: Thank you. Why is it that when I use \label in the align environment, the equations don't display but rather the underlying mathjax code?

Comment: @EvanAad: There seems to be a problem when editing. I find that when I save the edit and reload the page, things look okay. The same thing happened while I was editing my answer.

Comment: See [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11392/mathjax-preview-broken-when-equations-contain-labels) for some details about why that is the case.  Also, see the [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) script for workarounds to this and many other small issues .

Comment: But how was this done? I can't edit this answer, so I can't see the source code.

Comment: @DanielMartin: I think that even if you can't edit an answer, you can right-click on a MathJax rendered formula and [a pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0KD0.png) will appear allowing you to choose "Show Math As > TeX Commands".

Comment: In the displayed equation you use \tag{1}. To refer to it you use \ref{a}. How does this work? I am not able to refer to \tagged equations. Am I missing the relevant part of MathJaX code?

Comment: @wdacda: The `\label{a}` is what is referenced by the `\ref{a}` which is displayed as $\ref{a}$.

Comment: @robjohn I get it now! With \tag{1} we control what will show as the "name" of the equation. We need the label to use it in \ref. Wonderful! I was quite slow. But better ever, then never. I prefer using \eqref, it is more like in math texts. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In order to see the tags during edit, the following trick can be used.

$$
\begin{aligned}
a & = b & (1) \\
c & = d & (2)
\end{aligned}
$$

But now the equations cannot be hyperlinked to.